# A way of changing the router link when the route is active in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to update the routerlink to something different.

I have a menu which I want to go to a different route when you click the link if you are on the active route (i.e. back to the homepage).

```
<a [routerLink]="['admin']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Admin</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the use-case but okay ;-)

You can simple make the routerLink a variable in your component so:

```
<a [routerLink]="[dynamicLink]" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Admin</a>
```

then in your component you can have:

```
public dynamicLink: string = "admin";
```

Then you can create some simple logic that tests if the current route is already 'admin' - and if so, change the dynamicLink variable to something else.